# ext4 File System got damaged due to improper write

Tags: partitioning, mount, external-hdd, data-recovery, ext4

This is what happened,

**I inserted my** (important) **external HDD into a RedHat 6 machine, did my task's, unmounted the drive via Nautilus, and physically detached the drive from the machine** *(and now I realized that, I detached the drive in a hurry while Nautilus (of RHEL6) was writing some thing to the disk).*

That hardisk had 3 partitions, *100GB ext4*, *50GB ext4* and remaining about *148GB ntfs*.

**Later I connected it again to my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, and now the two *ext4* partitions of the drive are not mounting.**

*Here is what Gparted says,*

[image]

*and,*

[image]

also, here is the `sudo fdisk -l` command's output,

> `Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, 320072932352 bytes`
>   `255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142446 sectors`
>   `Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes`
>   `Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes`
>   `I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes`
>   `Disk identifier: 0xf909bf11`
>
> `Device     Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System`
>    `/dev/sdb1             2048   209717247   104857600   83  Linux`
>    `/dev/sdb2        209717248   314574847    52428800   83  Linux`
>    `/dev/sdb3        314574848   625141759   155283456    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`

I am not that familiar to `fsck` or `fsck.ext4` command, please provide me a direction.

Comment: Well, you know the command to run: `fsck.ext4`. Include the device number as the argument (`fsck.ext4 /dev/sdb1`). Also, when in doubt, man pages help (`man fsck.ext4`).

Comment: @saiarcot895 - Thank you for your suggestion, I do know a bit of `fsck.ext4` and how to run it, but I don't know it's exact outcomes. Like will it reset the file system tables? or Will I be able to get my data back?, because I don't want to lose the data present in it.

Comment: I believe that it will try to recover the `ext4` superblock and try to complete any writes that weren't fully written to the disk (is currently in a journal). You can use the `-n` option initially to mount the filesystem in a read-only mode to get a status report.

Comment: @saiarcot895 - I just now tried what you suggested, the check dumped a whole lot of things while the *Pass 5: Checking group summary information*, also there were lots of *Free blocks count wrong for group #0 (23513, counted=23510). Fix? no* type questions, and at the end it said, *MyDisk: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

MyDisk: 11/6553600 files (1709.1% non-contiguous), 459349/26214400 blocks*

Comment: Well, something is definitely wrong, considering it says `1709.1% non-contiguous` and the 6553600 files and 26214400 blocks. As it is, the `-n` option effectively prevents any changes from being made. If you run it without the `-n` option, `fsck` will be allowed to fix the filesystem.

Comment: @saiarcot895 - Ohk! I will try is out! Thanks buddy.

Comment: The very first thing you should do is go buy another HDD and copy the entirety of the original drive to the new HDD: `sudo dd if=/dev/sdN of=/dev/sdNN`.  Any suggestion has the potential of damaging your data even further and if this data is truly important, please back it up!

Comment: @earthmeLon - Thank you for your suggestion! I have done it already! Now waiting for appropriate solution over it!

Answer (score 1):

Run this for both sdb1 & sdb2. If external drive and you are sure everything is unmounted, you can run from inside your working Ubuntu. Others may need to use live installer.

From liveDVD/Flash so everything is unmounted,swap off if necessary, change example shown with partition sdb1 to your partition(s)

e2fsck is used to check the ext2/ext3/ext4 family of file systems. -p trys fixes where response not required

```
sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sdb1
```

if errors: -y auto answers yes for fixes needing response

```
sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sdb1
```

also see:

```
man e2fsck
```

Answer (score 0):

Four things to consider!

First you should really try mounting it back on the original device this last worked on.  If this is the case you can back up your data from there, then wipe the drive in it entirety.

Second, the partitions are possibly not mounting because you were in the middle of writing something, Windows is retarded the same way when a CD is removed, all user interaction is prompted to put the CD in or else.  So simply putting the harddrive back in would work, but only if you still had the machine running.  Some cases, however, can revert last made changes.

Third, your partition table file, for the name I cannot recall, is most likely destroyed and corrupted.

Fourth, you should never, ever ever ever ever, remove a drive while its in use, ever.

If the first three cannot fix your issue, then back what data you can and call in a pro to recover the "Lost" data you cannot.  Sadly HDD problems are mostly irreversible and permanent, with no work around possible without ruining the drive or its contents further.  It's why everyone tells you redundantly to back your content up.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! And ya! about that fourth point, will always make sure!